# Exporting image generated by a camera in Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, sdk, camera

I am navigating the SDK provided by a microscope camera supplier and face a challenge understanding how the image is processed. For those interested, the camera is this on: http://www.touptek.com/product/showproduct.php?id=285&lang=en.

In the unique python example provided by the supplier, here is how the image is generated and displayed in a Qt GUI interface:

First, the script finds the camera using the uvcham.py file provided in the SDK.

```
a = uvcham.Uvcham.enum()
self.hcam = uvcham.Uvcham.open(a[0].id)
```

Then, the scripts extract the resolution, width, height, and bufsize (don't know what this is):

```
self.hcam.put(uvcham.UVCHAM_FORMAT, 2)      # format: RGB888
res = self.hcam.get(uvcham.UVCHAM_RES)
self.w = self.hcam.get(uvcham.UVCHAM_WIDTH | res)
self.h = self.hcam.get(uvcham.UVCHAM_HEIGHT | res)
bufsize = ((self.w * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4) * self.h
self.buf = bytes(bufsize)       
self.hcam.start(self.buf, self.cameraCallback, self)
```

(see the following chunk of code for self.cameraCallback)

It then emits the image (eventImage is a pyqtSignal())

```
@staticmethod
    def cameraCallback(nEvent, ctx):
        if nEvent == uvcham.UVCHAM_EVENT_IMAGE:
            ctx.eventImage.emit()
```

and lastly it displays the image in the Qt GUI using the following code:

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def eventImageSignal(self):
        if self.hcam is not None:
            self.total += 1
            self.setWindowTitle('{}: {}'.format(self.camname, self.total))
            img = QImage(self.buf, self.w, self.h, (self.w * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4, QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
```

So, now my question is what if I want to save a video? How can I handle the different part of this script to store somewhere, and properly, the multiple frames generated by the camera, and which are here displayed in a Qt GUI, and later turn these multiples frames into a video?

I know how to do such operations with OpenCV, but here it's different I think, the image is generated using its buf, width, height, and some calculations that I don't understand.

I tried using OpenCV directly to handle this camera using the following classical function:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(1+cv2.CAP_ANY)
```

and the problem is that the camera is not stable when handled that way through openCV and directshow (a few frame sometimes display X/Y offset and/or color issue). In contrast, the camera, and the images it produced, are very stable when using the method described in the first part of my post (with the Qt GUI).

Have anyone here ever worked with such a way to generate image from a camera using resolution, width, height, buf (?), and could help me navigate this? My final objective here is to be able to record videos using this camera via an automated method (meaning through lines of code, so my need to understand these lines of codes rather than using the manual software provided by the supplier).

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `bufsize` seems to be the total number of bytes that it takes to store one raw image. Each pixel seems to have a bit-depth of 24 bits, which makes sense since the format is `RGB888`. `buf` is the actual data buffer itself (the bytes that make up the image). The fourth argument passed into `QImage` is the bytes per line / bytes per row (`(self.w * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4`)

Comment: Thank you, so you mean that self.buf = bytes(bufsize) is my actual image? How could I save this into a jpg or png image, from which I can later build my video?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `buf` is the collection of bytes that make up the actual image. These bytes just encode the raw pixel data, which means they don't correspond to any particular image format yet, like JPG or PNG, because there is no metadata/headers associated with those bytes. In their current state, they kind of resemble a BMP image. If you want a sequence of individual JPGs or PNGs, I'd probably try PIL/Pillow to create images from bytes. You may be able to export your images as a single GIF, even. If you're looking for a movie format like MP4, I'd try MoviePy (not pymovie).